# Дан input.Заменить четные символы в строке на знак "?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, строки, input

Использую input и кнопку для получения данных из оного. Js имею такой вот код:

```js
function getDataFromInput() {
  var str;
  str = $("#msg").val();
  var arr;
  arr = str.split('');

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
      arr[i] = "?";
    }
  }
  print(arr);
}

function print(arr) {
  $("#word").html(arr);
}
```

Код выполняется только если вводишь в input варинаты типа : 12345678. Тогда четный символ заменяется корректно. Но если ввести что-то типа: 1223365879952. То заменяются только четные числа,а не четный символ. С буквами вообще не работает. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке

arr[i] % 2 берет i-е число из инпута и делит на 2, работа идет с числами, а не с индексом. именно поэтому твой код заменяет четные числа, а не символы. для работы с символами дели сам индекс i % 2

Но в ответе выше уже дано решение красивее)

Comment: Не числа ([и даже не цифры](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988)), а символы, которые являются строками, которые приводятся к числам арифметичеким оператором.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>   if (arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {} else {
> ```

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2) {
```

Comment: Прошу прощения,но с данной правкой не работает и то,что работало(

Comment: Потому что у тебя открывалось 2 фигурные скобки, а в новом варианте только одна. Удали лишнюю закрывающуюся.

Comment: Мой IDE(WebStorm) показывает ошибку в синтаксисе. Но else я вообще убрал.

Answer (score 1):

Итак! Финальный вариант кода,которые заменяет именно четный по счету символ в строке,будь она представлена числами,или буквами выглядит так:

```js
function getDataFromInput() {
  var str;
  str = $("#msg").val();
  var arr;
  arr = str.split('');

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      arr[i] = "?";
    }
  }
  print(arr);
}

function print(arr) {
  $("#word").html(arr);
}
```

Благодарю за помощь!